# Prove that $2^n +1$ is divisible by $3$ for all positive integers $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I just want to know if I went on the right direction. With induction

Let $n=1$, then $2^1+1= 3$, which is divisible by $3$. Then show proof for 
$n+1.$

$2^n+1=3k$

So we get $2^{n+1}+1, \rightarrow 2^n+2+1, \rightarrow 3k+3= 3(k+1)$. Thus $2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$.

Now if I wanted to show that $2^n+1$ is divisble by $3$, $\forall$ odd integers $n$.
Would it be with induction:

$n=1$, then $2+1=3$, and $3|3$.
Let $n=2k+1$, since n is odd, then we get $2^{2k+1}+1=3m$. Now we need to show for $k+1$.

We get: $2^{2k+2+1}+1=3m \rightarrow 2^{2k+1}*2^2+4-3 \rightarrow 4(2^{2k+1}+1)-3$

$\rightarrow 4(3m)-3 \rightarrow 3(4m-1)$, thus $2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: are you sure? if $n=2$ we get $$2^2+1=5$$

Comment: $2^2+1=5$ is not divisible by $3$. You mean *odd* integers $n$.

Comment: $4$th line is wrong. $2^{n+1}=2^n\cdot 2$ and not $2^n +2$ as you wrote

Comment: By FT= Factor Theorem $\,3=2-(-1)\mid 2^n-(-1)^n\, (= 2^n+1\,$ by $n$ odd). See the dupe for many ways to prove FT (which can be specialized to direct proofs here if so desired, including all proofs below) $\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- $2^1+1=3$;
- $2^{2n+1}+1=3m\implies4(3m)-3=2^{2(n+1)+1}+1=3m'$.

Answer (score 5):

But it is not true, say $n=2$. :(

If $n$ is odd then $2^n+1 = (2+1)(2^{n-1}-...+1) =3k$, then is true.

Comment: Try $n=-1$. I think $-1$ is an odd integer number.

Comment: In that case $2^n+1$ it is not even an integer

Comment: If so by your way for $n=2$ we get: $2^2+1=5=3k$, where $k=\frac{5}{3}$.

Comment: Which way...? What are you trying to prove Michael?

Answer (score 3):

This is only true for *odd* integers $n=2k+1$:

$$2^{2k+1}+1 = 2^{2k+1}-(-1)^{2k+1} = (2+1) (2^{2k}-2^{2k-1}\pm\cdots+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

If you need to prove it for odd $n$, then here is an elegant proof

$$2^n=(3-1)^n$$
$$=3k+(-1)^n$$
Since $n$ is odd , $(-1)^n=-1$

Also proving $2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$ is same as proving $2^n-2$ is divisible by $3$

Therefore
$$ 2^n-2= (3-1)^n-2$$
$$=3k+(-1)^n-2$$
$$=3k-1-2$$
$$3k-3 $$
And this is divisible by $3$ for all $n\in \mathbb N(odd)$

And of course it is not true for every even $n$

Answer (score 2):

$2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$ only when $n = 2k+1, (k∈\mathbb{Z}^*)$.

Use modulus:

For every odd number $n$, we have
$$2^n≡2 (\mod n)$$
and for every even number $n$, we have
$$2^n≡1 (\mod n)$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that for all n = odd positive integers,
a+b|a^n+b^n
Therefore,
3 i.e. 2+1|2^n+1^n for n is odd positive integer

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).