# Question to the proof: $2^n+1$ is divisible by 3 for every odd number n

Tags: proof-explanation

I've came across this post:

[Prove that $2^n +1$ is divisible by $3$ for all positive integers $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475298/prove-that-2n-1-is-divisible-by-3-for-all-positive-integers-n/2475320)

and the very last comment suggests to prove the above statement through

$2^=(3−1)^    =3+(−1)^$

I don't quite understand how one can conclude the last part.
What I thought so far is that 3k is standing obviously for a number, which is divisible by 3 - however I don't see where this assumption comes from and what I am most interested in, how come the part with $(−1)^$?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Expand $(3-1)$, $(3-1)^2$, and $(3-1)^3$, see if you can see the pattern.

Comment: @miracle173: 2 is not odd.

Comment: $2^{2n+1}=2\cdot 4^n\equiv 2\pmod 3$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful.  There is now just one thing I didn't get.. Why is $4^n$ the same as mod 3?

Comment: The powers of $2$ taken modulo $3$ are $1,2,1,2,1,2,\cdots$.

Comment: The simplest is $2\equiv-1$ so that $2^n+1\equiv(-1)^n+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the binomial theorem
$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{t=0}^n{n \choose t}x^ky^{n-k}$$
to show this. We have

$$\begin{array}{}2^n\\&=(3-1)^n\\&=\sum_{t=0}^n{n \choose t}\cdot 3^t\cdot(-1)^{n-t}\\&={n \choose 0}\cdot 3^0\cdot(-1)^{n-0}+\sum_{t=1}^n{n \choose t}\cdot 3^t\cdot(-1)^{n-t}\\&=(-1)^n+3\sum_{t=1}^n{n \choose t}\cdot 3^{t-1}\cdot(-1)^{n-t}\\&=3k+(-1)^n\end{array}$$
where $$k=\sum_{t=1}^n{n \choose t}\cdot 3^{t-1}\cdot(-1)^{n-t}$$

Comment: Note that $(3-1)^n\equiv (-1)^n\mod 3$ and you are done.

Comment: @PatBol that was not the question of the OP. The OP asked how to show $(3−1)^ =3+(−1)^$ and it seems that the OP (or the comment he is referencing) wants to avoid modular arithmetic.